# How to stop compile error for missing d.ts file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

The code runs, but the compile error is driving me nuts.

I have got the following line in my .ts file. Unfortunately the LINQ library does not yet have a d.ts file. So it's causing compile error, even though the javascript runs as designed.

```
import linq = require('linq');
```

Which is defined already in require.js bootstrap as follow:

```
define('linq', ['jquery','linq'], function($,linq) {
    return Enumerable; });
```

I don't need typescript to act like it knows more than the coder. If that's the case might as well throw it aside and stick with native javascript. Again the code works, but the compile check does not.

Any idea how to fix my code or tell the ts compiler to get outta the way?

Comment: Hi, we have on DT a type definition to linqjs. Take a look https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/linq

Comment: https://github.com/schungx/LINQ-to-TypeScript has .d.ts for the linqjs library (which is probably what you're using).

Comment: Will check them out! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the following

```
declare module 'linq'{
   var foo:any;
   export = foo;
}
```

in a new `.d.ts` and then you are good to go.